# Call to webservice in Node always returns an error condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a the following function which (eventually) will be used to save a record

```
exports.save = function(req,res) {
    var userProfile = new UserProfile();

    try {
        var i = 0;
        var startPos = 0;
        var nameLength = 0;

        console.log("Saving profile");
        strPos = req.body.displayName.indexOf(' ');
        nameLength = req.body.displayName.length;

        userProfile._id     = req.body.id;
        userProfile.email   = req.body.emailAddress;

        if (nameLength > 0) {
            userProfile.givenName   = req.body.displayName.substring(0, strPos);
            userProfile.familyName  = req.body.displayName.substring(nameLength,strPos+1);
        }
        else {
            userProfile.givenName   = userProfile.givenName;
            userProfile.familyName  = "";
        }

        userProfile.displayName = req.body.displayName;

        console.log("well that bit worked - now hows about returning to the calling page");

        // processed OK
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('OK');
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("Oh dear - something broke");
        console.log(e.message);
    }
};
```

This is routed to by the following line in Node.

```
app.post('/saveProfile',profile.save);
```

and called from a webpage by the following jquery code.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/saveProfile',
                data: JSON.stringify(userProfile),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset = utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('OK!')
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert('Returned error ' + err);
                }
            });
```

According to Fiddler I am getting the following response

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 14:56:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

2
OK
0

However the error is always called - no error message is returned. I have checked that the setting of the response header is called by echoing to the console a message.

So what am I doing wrong in the return from the save function which means the calling page thinks an error has occured, or at least does not think it is successful. I have tried calling from both Chrome and IE.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are returning a `text/plain` response to a request which expects `application/json`.

Comment: Thanks Achrome - that done it - I was testing so returning back text before moving on to the actual save - I shall now call myself Homer Simpson for the rest of the day :)